# How to get graylog running behind a proxy?

Tags: configuration, graylog2, graylog

I've installed the most graylog, and it all appears to be working - up until I actually try to search for something. Then it complains that it is unable to connect. I believe the problem is that it is trying to use the same ip address to connect from the client, as it is from the server (although this seems like astonishingly bad design, so I may well be misunderstanding it).

My understanding is that it is using one of rest_listen_uri or rest_transport_uri (not sure which, the docs don't differentiate them) to query the server, which then makes another query to the same address to get the data.

The problem is that the ip address that I use to connect from another machine, is different to the ip address by which it can access itself. So if I set it to one ip, the ajax call succeeds, and I get an error from the server. If I set it to the other ip, then queries run from the command line of the server itself will work, but queries from any other machine can't reach it.

Is there any way to fix this? Or should I just use the previous version, which didn't have this problem?